# unrecognized color `00000f' with Convert Command

Tags: php, shell, command, imagemagick

I am getting the error while trying to run convert command. Here is the command.

```
convert -colorspace rgb 10338_1.ai -transparent 00000f 10338_1.png
```

and i am getting the error is

```
convert: unrecognized color `00000f' @ color.c/GetColorInfo/965.
```

Any Solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert transparent AI image to transparent png image.Here is the post

http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366

Comment: Please post a link to your image.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hhqp65q7e1gna6/1.ai?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color should be given in HTML notation with hash in front of it:

```
convert -colorspace rgb 10338_1.ai -transparent '#00000f' 10338_1.png
```

Comment: Yes, this way I can do, but you know by using this the png image generated is with white background. not transparent background. If i write white instead, it generated perfect but also strips white color of image

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366 from this post

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The colour #00000f is almost black, not white.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Who told about white?

Comment: OP mentioned white in his first comment.

Comment: guys, what i mean here is to make transparent image, White mean to strip that color from background only, may this post will help you to understand the scenario,   http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct about the hashtag.  For more info see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php.

Comment: Yes, this way I can do, but you know by using this the png image generated is with white background. not transparent background. If i write white instead, it generated perfect but also strips white color of image. this is the original post

http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366


Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can analyse your image by looking at its histogram, like this:

```
convert a.ps -format "%c" histogram:info:
608007: (    0,    0,    0,    0) #0000000000000000 cmyk(0,0,0,0)
 58793: (    0,    0,    0,65535) #000000000000FFFF cmyk(0,0,0,255)
  6551: (    0,    0,    0,34952) #0000000000008888 cmyk(0,0,0,136)
  5095: (    0,    0,    0,48059) #000000000000BBBB cmyk(0,0,0,187)
  4350: (    0,    0,    0,17476) #0000000000004444 cmyk(0,0,0,68)
  3297: (    0,    0,    0,61166) #000000000000EEEE cmyk(0,0,0,238)
  2897: (    0,    0,    0, 4369) #0000000000001111 cmyk(0,0,0,17)
```

First, you notice it is in CMYK colourspace, not RGB. You can see that the predominant colour is black with 608007 pixels, and that all the other colours in the image are actually just shades of black, but all have zero values for the CMY components. That means you lose nothing by just extracting the blacks into a greyscale image like this:

```
convert a.ps -channel K out.png
```

[image]

Maybe now you can do what you want, for example you can set the white pixels transparent like this:

```
convert out.png -transparent white result.png
```

Comment: hi mark, thanks for your reply, but by this syntax, I am not able to make transparent image, As AI file is transparent and the png generate with this is with white background. The above syntax is working fine in my local machine. 

May this link help you to understand, 
http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366

and also see the image,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/707sngb8ral8y8x/9801_1.png?dl=0

is generated by my local machine, which is transparent